# ReactJS shows alert message when link is clicked

Tags: reactjs

The following code shows the alert message as the rules are being bound in the `map()` function. I do not want this to happen. Instead, how can I bind the `onClick()` to each link so when the user clicks the link the message then will show? I think it has to do with placing `bind(this)` somewhere in the `map()` code but cannot figure it out. Thanks for any help!

```js
const RuleResults = React.createClass({
  showMessage: function (rule) {
    if (rule.ShowMessageToUser == true) {
      alert(rule.MessageToUser);
    }
  },
  render: function () {

    var rules = this.props.businessRules.map((rule) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href={rule.HREF} onClick={this.showMessage(rule)} target='_blank'>{rule.Name}</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {rules}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass to `onClick` reference to function instead of call it. To do it you can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

1. `<a href={rule.HREF} onClick={ this.showMessage.bind(this, rule) }>..</a>`
2. `<a href={rule.HREF} onClick={ () => this.showMessage(rule) }>..</a>`

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41858/)